# The wrong shared library is being linked

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to link against a modified version of a library (LAME).

I downloaded the source, made the modifications and build the shared object file.

I then copied the shared library file into the `./lib` folder of the project I wanted to link to. The other project was just a trivial harness to test my modifications. I also copied the relevant header from LAME's `./include`.

I built my harness:

```
gcc -c  src/harness.c -o obj/harness.o
gcc obj/harness.o -o bin/harness -L./lib/ -libmp3lame
```

But to my suprise:

```
$ ldd ./bin/harness
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbc5fe000)
libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f10d9468000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10d90a0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f10d8d9b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10d9713000)
```

(The `/usr/lib/...` library was linked instead of the one in `./lib` in the harness' project directory.

I then changed the name of my customised libmp3lame.so to libsomeothername.so and tried to link that.. the same thing happened - the installed libmp3lame was linked instead of my custom one.

What is going on here? Why won't the compiler just do what it's told? Why would `/usr/lib/.../libmp3lame` get linked *even when that name isn't used*?

Answer (score 4):

I used `LD_DEBUG=all` to see what was happening with the linker, as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` should have linked to the correct library.

As it turned out, the linker *was* looking there, but expected to find `libmp3lame.so.0` rather than the `libmp3lame.so` I had there. Renaming the library with `.0` on the end fixed the problem.

I can now run:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./bin/harness
```

and the lib I wanted is linked.

`LD_DEBUG=all` seems pretty useful.

Comment: how is `LD_DEBUG=all` used?

Comment: @nate I had the same question and found this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541310/1442500

Answer (score 1):

The [ld-linux.so](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) library is the one that actually controls which library gets linked in at run time. The -L option to GCC, on the other hand, only affects the compile-time search path for libraries.

The man page says:

> When resolving library dependencies, the dynamic linker first inspects
>   each dependency string to see if it contains a slash (this can occur
>   if a library pathname containing slashes was specified at link time).
>   If a slash is found, then the dependency string is interpreted as a
>   (relative or absolute) pathname, and the library is loaded using that
>   pathname.

If there is no slash, then it searches along the pre-defined search path (also specified in the man page).

To get the behaivour you want, you have the following options:

1. Specify the absolute path to the library when linking, or
2. Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the directory containing your library, or
3. Use the -rpath option when linking to include the directory containing your library in the search path (NB. to pass linker options from gcc to the linker, use `-Wl,--rpath=/my/path`

Comment: `gcc obj/harness.o -o bin/harness -L/home/manko/Repos/lamexperiment/lib/ -lmp3lame -Wl,--rpath=/home/manko/Repos/lamexperiment/lib` and then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/manko/Repos/lamexperiment/lib ldd ./bin/harness` still doesn't work, i.e I get `libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007fc2d74df000)`

Comment: yeah, absolute path won't do it.